# The meaning of having the same number of principal components as the number of predictive features and using it in my ML model

Tags: machine-learning, python, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have 4 predictive features and 4800 observations. I did PCA fit like this:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=X_train_scaled.shape[1],whiten=True)
pca.fit(X_train_scaled)
```

and I got

[image]

I have a few question regarding this:

Does this mean that the first feature, which is `age` in this case, is the most important?
I know that this is the variance of principle components, but why are there 4 PCs just like the features? what can I infer from this plot about my predictive features?

In other words, how can this help me in the down-stream analysis in regards to choosing maybe the best features from the 4?

Comment: Yes, Thanks! but I still have this one question: so the PCs are the new features, instead of the original 4. Each PC is a linear combination of features, right? so how can I find which features are in PC1, and PC2 and so on... ? in other words, why is the variance in PC1 for example, higher than the variance of PC2 ? is PC1 a result of different linear combination? If so, which features participated in PC1?

Comment: You just need to read more about PCA.  All of that (& more!) is covered in various places on the site.  Click on the [tag:pca] tag, sort by votes, & start reading some of the most influential threads.  You might also try the wikipedia page for PCA, & Python's help pages for your functions.